# How to populate multilevel KendoTree view with nested JSON data in Angular 5

Tags: json, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-treeview

I am trying to populate nested JSON data into multilevel KendoTreeView.

```
public nodes: any[] = [{
      "moduleId": 1,
      "moduleName": "Mode",
      "features": [
        {
          "featureId": 2,
          "featureName": "F1",
          "subFeatures": [],
          "privileges": [
            {
              "privilegeId": 2,
              "privilegeName": "P2"
            },
            {
              "privilegeId": 12,
              "privilegeName": "P2E"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "featureId": 3,
          "featureName": "F2",
          "subFeatures": [
            {
              "featureId": 4,
              "featureName": "F21",
              "subFeatures": [],
              "privileges": [
                {
                  "privilegeId": 4,
                  "privilegeName": "P4"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "privileges": [
            {
              "privilegeId": 3,
              "privilegeName": "P3"
            }
          ]
        }
    ]
}]
```

**Using this code I could only see one level tree. Not sure how to use [hasChildren]="hasChildren" in this scenario.**

`*So far I tried this to get some data populated in the Kendo TreeView.*
Data looks like this.

```
<kendo-treeview [nodes]="node"
                [textField]="[ 'moduleName','featureName']"
                [childrenField]="['features']"
                kendoTreeViewExpandable
                kendoTreeViewHierarchyBinding>
</kendo-treeview>`
```

Thanks in Advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tree component directly supports just one field for the node name. So you have to use a Node template to find the right attribute for displaying the node name.
Further for children and haschildren you have to add some code that tells which attribute contains the children and does that attribute have a content. 
So your structure is:

```
Module
  Feature
    Subfeature
```

Each level has to be supported by custom code.

Template:

```
 <kendo-treeview
     textField="moduleName"
     [nodes]="nodes"
     [children]="children"
     [hasChildren]="hasChildren"
 >
 <ng-template kendoTreeViewNodeTemplate let-dataItem>
        {{dataItem.moduleName || dataItem.featureName}}
    </ng-template>
 </kendo-treeview>
```

HasChildren:

```
 public hasChildren = (dataitem: any): boolean => !!dataitem.features || !!dataitem.subFeatures;
```

Children:

```
 public children = (dataitem: any): Observable<any[]> => of(dataitem.features || dataitem.subFeatures);
```

I have prepared a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hbjccw) that works with your data.

Comment: Hi @Ludwig, Can I get some help in TreeView populating  Module-Feature-Subfeature-Privilage for the JSON data mentioned above.
Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Module
  Feature
    Subfeature
    Privilages
```

I am trying to get the above tree pattern. What modifications should I try to meet the requirement 
public children = (dataitem: any): Observable => of(dataitem.features || dataitem.subFeatures || dataitem.privileges);

I tried but it either gives me Privilages or Subfeatures but not both as the same time.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Look at this Stackblitz. Look at the ng-template and the hasChildren and children properties. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hbjccw-zvtw55

Comment: @Ludwig Thanks for the help, This was the exact solution I was looking for.